# How to display state passed from another component

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am basically trying to show a button with a number (initial value 1), and when you click on that button the number increases by one. I have two components, a main App component and a Button component for the button. The App component passes the Button component a function that updates the number. But when I load all this, it gives me this error:

```
TypeError: this.state is null
render
src/Button.js:6

  export class Button extends React.Component {
  render() {
  return (
> <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>
  {this.state.count}
  </button>
  );
```

So my questions are:
1 Why does it give me this error?
2 What have I done wrong in the App component that might break the button?

I have even tried removing the onClick attribute in Button's render function, and it gives me this error:

```
TypeError: this.state is null
render
src/Button.js:6

  export class Button extends React.Component {
  render() {
  return (
> <button>
  {this.state.count}
  </button>
  );
```

App.js:

```
import {Button} from './Button';

export class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {count: 1};
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    let currentCount = this.state.count;
    this.setState({count: (currentCount + 1)});
    console.log('handleClick()');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo"/>
          <Button onClick={this.handleClick} />

        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Button.js:

```
export class Button extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>
        {this.state.count}
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

index.js (the file that renders App):

```
import {App} from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

I expected it to be a button that contained the number which would be increased by 1 every time you clicked the button, but instead it gave me the errors I showed above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't define any state in `Button`, thus it is null. Remember : states are *local* to components. You need props (or context) to propagate information from one component to another.

You have to pass `App`'s state down to `Button` as a prop too. Then, you render your counter from the prop :

```
<Button count={this.state.count} onClick={this.handleClick} />

// then :

export class Button extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>
        {this.props.count}
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```